# normalizeLink function not working, breadcrumb links not working javascript html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, breadcrumbs

Relatively quick question for you(Or so I think!), on my webpage it displays breadcrumb links when a certain topic is selected from an index. When these breadcrumb links are displayed and a user clicks on any of them, the page goes blank(its supposed to redirect them depending on which breadcrumb link they select). I've looked through the code of the webpage and I found the function that deals with that, the problem is im not the one that coded it so I dont know where to edit/what to do since currently i am just an intern. Here is the function:

```
 // normalize links
            $('#breadcrumbLinks a, #navigationLinks a').each(function () {
                var oldLink = $(this).attr('href');
                // we generate from oxygen '../'s in from of link
                while (oldLink.indexOf('../') == 0) {
                    info('strip \'../\' from ' + oldLink);
                    oldLink = oldLink.substring(3);
                }
                $(this).attr('href', stripUri(oldLink));
            });
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.") == -1) {
              showParents();
              $('#frm').contents().find('table.nav').hide();
            } else {

            }
        }
        $('#frm').show();
        $('div.tooltip').remove();
        $('#breadcrumbLinks').find('a').after('<span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>');
        $('#breadcrumbLinks').find('span').last().html('&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        $('.navparent a').click(function () {
            if ($.cookie("wh_pn") != "" && $.cookie("wh_pn") !== undefined && $.cookie("wh_pn") !== null) {
                currentTOCSelection = parseInt($.cookie("wh_pn"));
                parentTOCSelection = $('#tree li:eq(' + currentTOCSelection + ')').parents('ul').parents('li').index('li');
                $.cookie('wh_pn', parentTOCSelection);
            }
        });
        $('.navprev a').click(function () {
            prevTOCSelection = parseInt($.cookie('wh_pn')) -1;
            $.cookie('wh_pn', prevTOCSelection);
        });
        $('.navnext a').click(function () {
            nextTOCSelection = parseInt($.cookie('wh_pn')) + 1;
            $.cookie('wh_pn', nextTOCSelection);
        });

        highlightSearchTerm(searchedWords);
```

The question is, how would i go about fixing this bug so that when the user selects a breadcrumb link they are redirected to that specific page?

Any help would be appreciated! thank you :)

Comment: _“how would i go about fixing this bug”_ – by finding its cause first, which is called _debugging_. So what have you done so far in this regard?

Comment: Well im assuming that the section of code that redirects the URL would be this:

$('.navprev a').click(function () {
            prevTOCSelection = parseInt($.cookie('wh_pn')) -1;
            $.cookie('wh_pn', prevTOCSelection);
        });
        $('.navnext a').click(function () {
            nextTOCSelection = parseInt($.cookie('wh_pn')) + 1;
            $.cookie('wh_pn', nextTOCSelection);

I can't figure out what 'wh_pn' is, i searched for its declaration but i could not find it. I apologize for my limited knowledge of html